# Crear un object asincrono

Tags: objeto

Alguna idea de como puedo implementar algo como lo siguiente

```
var fx = await new Sma(params...)
```

El punto es que la clase Sma tiene una propiedad "this.y" la cual es un arreglo que se llena en el constructor a partir de una funcion asincrona y al ejecutar lo siguiente

```
var fx = new Sma(params...)
fx.plot()
```

el metodo plot lanza un error que indica que this.y[0] no esta definido o sea que el arreglo no tiene valores aun y es porque la funcion asincrona que llena la propiedad this.y aun no a devuelto los valores al ejecutarse el metodo plot(). La propiedad "y" es independiente del metodo plot asi que si pensaban que la solucion es llenar la propiedad y dentro del metodo plot no es lo que busco ya que no siempre va a ser necesario plotear un objecto Sma pero si es necesario que la propiedad y tenga datos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! primer punto ultra importante... en que lenguaje??? porque esto pueden ser miles.. usa el boton [edit] y aclara en que lenguaje estas trabajando...

Comment: `await` implica devolver una promesa, `new` implica devolver un objeto del tipo indicado. O devuelves una promesa, o devuelves un objeto del tipo creado.... Más bien tendrás que hacer que tu lógica sea asíncrona también, por ejemplo hacer que tu objeto en `fx.plot()` devuelva la promesa con los datos, en vez de los datos directamente. Por cierto... lo normal sería que tu objeto reciba los datos, no que los solicite de manera asíncrona... eso solo añade complejidad innecesaria, desde mi punto de vista. Aunque tal vez tenga sentido en tu caso, es difícil saberlo sin ver el código claro